# Why is this (presumably more efficient) dynamic algorithm being outperformed by the naive recursive version?

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, big-o, dynamic-programming

I have the following problem as homework:

> Write a O(N^2) algorithm to determine whether the string can be broken into a list of words. You can start by writing an exponential algorithm and then using dynamic programming to improve the runtime complexity.

The naive exponential algorithm which I started out with is this:

```
def naiveWordBreak(S):
    if len(S) == 0:
        return True
    else:
        return any([(S[:i] in wordSet) and naiveWordBreak(S[i:]) for i in range(1, len(S) + 1)])
```

I then adapted this into the following dynamic algorithm:

```
def wordBreak(S):
    prefixTable = [False] * (len(S) + 1)
    prefixTable[0] = True
    return _helper(S, prefixTable)

def _helper(S, prefixTable):
    if prefixTable[len(S)]:
        return prefixTable[len(S)]
    else:
        for i in range(1, len(S) + 1):
            if S[:i] in wordSet and _helper(S[i:], prefixTable):
                prefixTable[i] = True
                return True
```

I am fairly confident from my proof and some testing that both algorithms are correct, however the recursive method should be exponential time while the dynamic method should be O(n^2). However, I got curious and used the `timeit` library to analyze the time it takes for both algorithms to run a batch of tests and the results were surprising. The dynamic method only beats the recursive method by a fraction of a second. More confusing is that after running the same test a couple of times, the recursive method actually gave a better runtime than the dynamic method. Here is the code I'm using for testing runtime:

```
def testRecursive():
    naiveWordBreak("alistofwords")
    naiveWordBreak("anotherlistofwords")
    naiveWordBreak("stableapathydropon")
    naiveWordBreak("retouchesreissueshockshopbedrollsunspotassailsinstilledintersectionpipitreappointx")
    naiveWordBreak("xretouchesreissueshockshopbedrollsunspotassailsinstilledintersectionpipitreappoint")
    naiveWordBreak("realignitingrains")


def testDynamic():
    wordBreak("alistofwords")
    wordBreak("anotherlistofwords")
    wordBreak("stableapathydropon")
    wordBreak("retouchesreissueshockshopbedrollsunspotassailsinstilledintersectionpipitreappointx")
    wordBreak("xretouchesreissueshockshopbedrollsunspotassailsinstilledintersectionpipitreappoint")
    wordBreak("realignitingrains")


def main():
    recTime = timeit.timeit(testRecursive, number=1)
    dynTime = timeit.timeit(testDynamic, number=1)

    print("Performance Results:\n")
    print("Time for recursive method = {}\n".format(recTime))
    print("Time for dynamic method = {}\n".format(dynTime))

    if dynTime < recTime:
        print("Dynamic method produces better performance")
    else:
        print("Recursive method produces better performance")
```

The way I see it, there are only a few explanations for why the runtimes are inconsistent/not what I expected:

- There is something wrong with my dynamic algorithm (or my analysis of it)
- There is something wrong with my recursive algorithm
- My test cases are insufficient
- `timeit` isn't actually an appropriate library for what I'm trying to do

Does anyone have any insights or explanations?

Comment: Can you explain what information `prefixTable` is caching? What does it represent when an index `i` is set to true?

Comment: @JohnKugelman yeah it should be naiveWordBreak, that was just a typo. I corrected it. The values in ```prefixTable``` indicates whether or not you can split S at that index into two substrings which can both be broken into a list of words. For example if ```prefixTable[i] == True``` then ```S[:i]``` and ```S[i:]``` are both strings which can be converted to lists of words.

Comment: `any([(S[:i] in wordSet) and naiveWordBreak(S[i:]) for i in range(1, len(S) + 1)])` has a serious flaw: it forces the entire list to be computed. Note that like most Python functions which work on sequences, `any` can be given a generator directly; there is no need to force evaluation into a list. Compare btilly's example between your version and the lazy-evaluation version `any((S[:i] in wordSet) and naiveWordBreak(S[i:]) for i in range(1, len(S) + 1))`. (You still get exponential performance if the argument is `"cannot" * n + "qq"`, assuming `qq` is not in the word set.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The naive recursive approach is only slow when there are many, many, ways to break up the same string into words.  If there is only one way, then it will be linear.

Assuming that `can`, `not` and `cannot` are all words in your list, try a string like `"cannot" * n`.  By the time you get to `n=40`, you should see the win pretty clearly.

Comment: Ahh I see, I ran some tests with inputs similar to what you described and the test results made a lot more sense. Thanks!